# help needed - tree view control

Tags: asp.net, controls, treeview, parent-child

I want to generate a control to represent fields and their subfields like tree view(graphical representation) with parent and child nodes in asp.net. It can be 'n' levels. how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Er...use the [ASP.NET TreeView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4fz6xk2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: thnks. im looking for something like organizational chart in order to represent the fields and modify nodes by click any nodes